# I want to use a string containing spaces in my URL, how?

Tags: php, html

```
$name='joseph john mathew';

$urlPgN ="<a href=author_stories.php?pgNo={pgNo}&name=$name style='text-decoration:none;color:#666; padding:0 2px 0 2px; '>{pgTxt}</a>";
```

I'm getting `localhost/rose/author_stories.php?pgNo=2&name=joseph` only. How can I do it so I get the full name in the URL?

Comment: You need to `urlencode()` the `$name` first; and use quotes around your attributes pls.

Comment: %20 can be your space, it's url encoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) and [urldecode](http://php.net/urldecode)

```
$name=urlencode('joseph john mathew');

$urlPgN ="<a href=\"author_stories.php?pgNo={pgNo}&name=$name\" style=\"text-decoration:none;color:#666; padding:0 2px 0 2px;\">{pgTxt}</a>";
```

And to fetch

```
$name = urldecode($_GET['name']);
```

Answer (score 2):

While you should use `urlencode`, you don't *need* to.  The real problem is due to the fact that you don't have quotes around the `href` attribute:

```
$urlPgN ="<a href='author_stories.php?pgNo={pgNo}&name=$name'
```

Using `urlencode($name)` can be done too and is more technically correct.

Do *not* use `urldecode` on `$_GET`/`$_POST`.  This is done automatically by PHP.

Comment: If `$name` comes from user input, using `urlencode()` is more than just technically correct.

Comment: When I say "don't *need* to," I don't mean you should skip doing it.  I just mean that it's not necessary for the link to still work in modern browsers.  Also be aware that `urlencode` is for *components* of the URL.  It won't work very well if you use it on the entire URL

Answer (score 0):

use urldecode and you are missing quotes for href attributes.

```
$urlPgN ="<a href='".urldecode('author_stories.php?pgNo='.$pgNo.'&name='.$name)."' style='text-decoration:none;color:#666; padding:0 2px 0 2px; '>$pgTxt</a>";
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: i got it : add $ for variables $pgNo and $pgTxt

Comment: $urlPgN ="<a href=\"author_stories.php?pgNo={pgNo}&name=$name\" style=\"text-decoration:none;color:#666; padding:0 2px 0 2px;\">{pgTxt}</a>";  this code work